# Are there gate-level ways to produce the min or max of two binary values?

Tags: digital-logic, electrical, computers, binary, alu

Some basics of digital logic are the **half-adder** and **full-adder**.  We know how to produce the *sum of two binary values* at the level of AND/OR/NOT gates, in a straightforward way presented in many textbooks.  (Never mind any advanced tricks used in real-world high performance chips.)   A few tweaks, and we can *subtract*.

What I don't recall ever seeing is gate-level ways to produce the *minimum* or *maximum* of two binary values.  Is there such a thing?  If so, do any microprocessors use it?

Comment: Relative comparisons require cascading through the bits and can't be performed with fewer than log n layers. Another two layers to AND and OR with the input values and you're done.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, what do you mean by "can't be performed with fewer than log n layers"? A big enough ROM could do it in 1 step.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I looked through my Big List of Gates, but couldn't find one called "ROM".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Think of it as a really wide fan-in sum-of-products.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There is no single gate that can solve this problem, even what you proposed. ROM LUT can certainly be constructed from gates just as your cascade system...

Comment: @ThePhoton: The switching speed of a single large N-input gate will be proportional to N when switching in the the "any" direction and to N^2 in the "all" direction [e.g. for a NAND, the "any" direction is "any input low: output high", and the "all" direction is "all inputs high: output low"]. A 32-input NAND function will generally not be implemented using a single 32-input gate, but instead as something like eight 4-input NAND gates which drive two 4-input NOR gates which in turn drive a two-input NAND. Such implementation would require more circuitry, but be much faster than using one gate.

Comment: @supercat, "impractically slow" is not the same as "can't be done".

Comment: @ThePhoton: I guess it depends what your objective is for trying to have fewer layers. If a "two layer" circuit would take more area than one with more layers, have a longer propagation time, and use more energy each time it switches, I would consider the fact that the circuit "could" be implemented in two layers to be of vague theoretical interest only.

Comment: @supercat, I wouldn't do it that way, but I wouldn't claim it "can't be done". The question specifically asks us to "Never mind any advanced tricks used in real-world high performance chips." So it is a question about what's theoretically possible, not the best way to implement things in the real world.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I suppose a good question then might be whether a gate with 32 transistors in series should be considered one "layer" or 32. If inputs are available in both inverted and non-inverted forms, *any* combinatorial function could be implemented to provide both normal and complemented outputs without any transistor's gate being wired to anything but the inputs. Most ROMs use two steps in addition to the input inversion, but combinatorial functions never "need" more than one. On the other hand, where did the OP ask about 'layers'? I think IVA was talking from a practical standpoint.

Answer (score 8):

Before considering the min/max, how about just comparing two numbers?  Let's say that you have two binary numbers:  A and B, and you want to know if A>B.  What you do is some simple subtraction, C=B-A.  If C is negative, then A was greater than B.  With a binary two's compliment number the most significant bit (MSB) will be 1 if the number is negative, and 0 if it is positive.  So after the subtraction, a single bit will tell you if A or B is larger.

Now, that was a super simple way to explain it.  There are some details that need to be paid attention to.

This works with signed numbers (two's compliment).  If A and B are unsigned, you will have to convert them to signed first.  All this really means is that you add a zero-bit on the left, and the resulting number is one bit larger.  For example, if A=1111(unsigned) then you need to make A=01111(signed).

The other issue is that you need to pay attention to the range of numbers that you are going to use, and make sure that you do not have any overflow/underflow conditions.  The usual way I deal with this is to give A and B an extra bit.  So an 8 bit signed number will become a 9 bit signed number.  You do this by duplicating the top (sign) bit.  For example, if A=1000(signed) then A will become 11000(signed).

Once you have correctly done the math, you can use the MSB of C to determine which number is larger.  You can then use a simple MUX to select A or B depending on the value of C's MSB.

Comment: Subtracting followed by selecting one or the other. Well, that's the obvious way, and currently what's done. I was hoping there'd be a more direct clever way.

Answer (score 0):

It's called magnitude comparator and uses less gates than the vanilla solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767316/finding-the-maximum-of-two-integers-in-binary-using-bit-logic-only .

The "vanilla" solution of computing the difference and looking at the MSB has the advantage of reusing known "parts" and might save you some design time, depending on your use case. You can at least save all but one gates for the output, since you will be looking only at the MSB.